# Changing Date object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to return a date function, from

```
Mon Jul 30 2012 10:57:56 GMT 0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

to

```
30 July 2012 10:57:56
```

Tried out most of the date functions, but still no answer/format.

Comment: Could you show us what date format the JSON object contains? A string with solely `Mon Jul 30 2012 10:57:56 GMT 0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`, and no property other than that about the date?

Comment: ??? You will have to explain a little more clearly what you want to do.
Do you want to format the date so it displays as "30 July 2012 10:57:56"? Did you try all of http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp ?

Answer (score 1):

Do not invent a bicycle, use library for this: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format